# Rally Excel Add-In Creation Date Query

Tags: rally

I am trying to run a query from the Excel add in to capture the # of defects in a certain date range.

For example:

```
Query: Defects Sprint 93
Type: Defect
Order: Creation Date
Columns: Creation Date
Filter: ((Creation Date >= 09/06/2012) AND (Creation Date 09/20/2012))
```

Note: I copy and pasted the *filter* string from the rally website.  When i ran this exact view in Rally i got the results I expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use ISO format for the dates and remove the space from the field name:

((CreationDate >= 2012-09-06) AND (CreationDate <= 2012-09-20))

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Kyle answer but little modification in my query it worked.
like ((CreationDate >= 2012-09-06) AND (CreationDate < 2012-09-21))

Note : in second CreationDate i increased the date by 1 from 20 to 21 ,it would satisfy the condition perfectly.